# PHP SQL Convert Select Statement into Variable for DB Insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently in the process of creating a Quiz Builder, I am having a slight issue with some DB inserts. What I am trying to do within the code is insert a Quiz Title and Description to the Quiz table which will in turn create a Quiz ID. I want to insert this Quiz ID along with Class ID values from the checkbox. Any suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I know I should be using prepare statements compared to what I am currently using. I am planning on fixing this issue once I get my main functionalities working.

```
 <form method="post" action="#">
                <p>
                    <label>Quiz Title: </label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Insert Quiz Title here" name="quizTitle" class="form-control" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Quiz Description: </label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Insert Quiz Description here" name="description" class="form-control"  />
                </p>

<?php

$showAllClasses = "SELECT * FROM class";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $showAllClasses) or die ('Error finding Classes');

$showClassesResult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $showAllClasses);

echo"<table border='1' cellpadding='10' align='center'>";

echo "<tr><th></th><th>Class ID</th><th>Class Name</th><th>Class 
Description</th></tr>";

 //while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  while ($row = $showClassesResult->fetch_object()){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='" .$row->classID . "' name='check_box[]' value='" .$row->classID . "'></td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row->classID . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row->className . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" .$row->classDesc . "</td>";
  //echo "<td><button type='button' name='add' id='add' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#questionType' class='btn btn-success'>Edit Students</button></td>";
  echo "</tr>";

}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//Get POST variables
$quizTitle = '"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['quizTitle']) . '"';
$description = '"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description']) . '"';
//echo $quizTitle;
//echo $description;

$getQuizIDQuery = "SELECT quizID FROM quiz ORDER BY quizID DESC LIMIT 1";

mysqli_query($mysqli, $getQuizIDQuery) or die ('Error getting Quiz ID');

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $getQuizIDQuery);
//$insertedQuizId = $mysqli->insert_id;

//Question query
$quizCreationQuery = "INSERT INTO quiz (quizTitle, description) VALUES($quizTitle, $description)";

foreach ($_POST['check_box'] as $classID) {

$ClassQuizQuery = "INSERT INTO quiz_class(classID, quizID) VALUES ('$classID', '$result')";

//$insert_ClassQuiz = $mysqli->query($ClassQuizQuery) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);


//Run Query
$insert_row = $mysqli->query($quizCreationQuery) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);

}
}
?>
    </table>
        <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" 
                    class="btn btn-info"/>
         </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: I strongly advise that you start using prepared statements now. They aren't any harder to learn than what you're doing already and they'll make your code safer. Plus, big advantage: when you post questions on Stack Overflow, people will stop annoying you by telling you to use prepared statements instead of answering your question :)

Comment: Haha, Thanks for the advice Matt

Comment: Its a bit messy ... thats probably one of the reasons why you got the order wrong. Right now you're trying to read the `quizID` before the new quiz is even created. Also ... in your `$ClassQuizQuery` you are using `mysql_result` as `quizID` instead of fetching the actual `quizID` from the result. If you separate the html and php a little, it might help you understand your own code a bit better e.g. move all the php code to the top and html to the bottom.

Comment: Hi the echo statements that you have commented. Are they working?

Comment: Yes the Echo statements are working, I have just commented them out as I don't currently need them until I can find a way to get the quidID and post it to a different DB table.

Comment: please mention the error that you are getting or output.

Comment: Btw. please feel free to post the answer youself once you fixed it (since both mistakes have been pointed out). Also ... you may want to stick with either procedural `mysqli_query()` or object oriented `$mysql->query()` syntax. You will just confuse yourself if you mix it =). I suggest using `$mysql->query()`. And as @RishiKc pointed out - next time you ask a question, you should include the exact error as well. It will help those who want to help you =)

Comment: Hi Nimmneun, I will post the answer once I get it fixed, thanks for your feedback. How do I go about turning the mysql_result into a variable which can be posted as $quizID?

Comment: you can just fetch and access it like your class result e.g. `$newQuizId = $result->fetch_object()->quizID`. Its basically the same as fechting a single result in the part of your code, where you iterate over the classes ... this one `$row = $showClassesResult->fetch_object()`

Comment: This is the error I am getting once I have rearranged a few things.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' )' at line 170

Comment: you still have the order wrong =) ... you have to insert the new quiz first, only after that will you be able to query for the new quizID. I'll post a working answer for you in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how a working example of your code could look like (with some of the suggested changes from the comments). I kept you original code mostly as is, but changed the placement and order within your script.

Serparating HTML and PHP is one of the things you should always aim for. Once you have all the PHP code closer together, remove duplicates or unnecessary stuff (including the superflous SELECT query for the last inserted id).

I added some comments for extra explanation. The rest ist mostly untouched =)

```
<?php


// first - all code that should always be executed,
// this will later be used in the html output.
$showAllClasses = "SELECT * FROM class";
$showClassesResult = $mysqli->query($showAllClasses) or die ('Error finding Classes');

// now the code that should only be executed on POST request
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // we only want things to happen if all queries are successful,
    // otherwise we end up with quizzes without class connections.
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();

    //Get POST variables
    $quizTitle = '"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['quizTitle']) . '"';
    $description = '"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description']) . '"';

    //Question query
    $quizCreationQuery = "INSERT INTO quiz (quizTitle, description) VALUES($quizTitle, $description)";
    $mysqli->query($quizCreationQuery) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);

    // The $mysqli instance knows the last inserted id, so we can just use that.
    $insertedQuizId = $mysqli->insert_id;

    foreach ($_POST['check_box'] as $classID) {
        $ClassQuizQuery = "INSERT INTO quiz_class(classID, quizID) VALUES ('$classID', $insertedQuizId)";
        $mysqli->query($ClassQuizQuery) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);
    }

    // Everything should have worked so we can now commit the transaction
    $mysqli->commit();
}

// now that we are done with everything, we start with the html output.
// since we have done all the complicated stuff above, all we have to care
// about, is the html output and iterating over our classes to create the html table.
?>

<form method="post" action="#">
    <p>
        <label>Quiz Title: </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Insert Quiz Title here" name="quizTitle" class="form-control"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Quiz Description: </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Insert Quiz Description here" name="description" class="form-control"/>
    </p>

    <table border='1' cellpadding='10' align='center'>
        <tr><th></th><th>Class ID</th><th>Class Name</th><th>Class Description</th></tr>
        <?php while ($row = $showClassesResult->fetch_object()): ?>
            <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' id='<?= $row->classID ?>' name='check_box[]' value='<?= $row->classID ?>'></td>
            <td><?= $row->classID ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->className ?></td>
            <td><?= $row->classDesc ?></td>
            <td><button type='button' name='add' id='add' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#questionType' class='btn btn-success'>Edit Students</button></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile ?>
    </table>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ill try this out now and then get back to you